# LD_LIBRARY_PATH not working while LD_PRELOAD works fine

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I am compiling a program on one machine and running it on another one which does not have compatible libstdc++ library. If I run it like this, that is using LD_PRELOAD, it runs fine.

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libstdc++.so.6 ./program args
```

However, If I try to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH, like shown below, it doesn't load the library and I get the error that I don't have the required libstdc++ version.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="./libstdc++.so.6"
./program args
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If libstdc++.so.6 is in the same directory as my program, can you tell how to use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH command for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to give paths in LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD ./program args
```

Answer (score 6):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, like `PATH`, takes a list of directories, not files.

If you want to put the current directory (**not** recommended) in there, you can:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

But it is always better to put absolute paths in there so that you don't pick up random garbage if you change directories.

For your specific problem, keeping `LD_PRELOAD` might actually be the best way to do it in case your executable has `rpath` settings (which might override the environment). Create a wrapper script that does it if you don't want to re-type it every time.